# Getting ref to props.children by React.cloneElement returns always null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am trying to get child ref in Wrapper component but it always returns null. I use the common code:

```
export const SelectableItem = ({ children }: Props) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => console.log(ref?.current), 1000); // returns null
    }, []);

    const child = React.Children.only(children);

    return React.cloneElement(child, { ref: (r) => (ref.current = r) });

};
```

```
<SelectableItem>
   <SomeChild />
</SelectableItem>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting that issue. The only thing I really changed was the console.log since it was producing an error. Hopefully you are able to figure out what was happening from the working code below.

```js
const SelectableItem = ({ children }: Props) => {
    const ref = React.useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(ref)
        }, 1000);
    }, []);
    
    const child = React.Children.only(children);

    return React.cloneElement(child, { ref: (r) => (ref.current = r) });
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SelectableItem>
      <div />
    </SelectableItem>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.querySelector('.react')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: In SomeChild component I have also ref={ref} on Box material ui . Can it be the reason?

Comment: I receive also "Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?" error

Comment: @Sheppard25, Are you passing the same ref to multiple children?

Comment: I have only one child there